# How to handle condition in ngrx/store with operation < or >

Tags: error-handling, null, ngrx, conditional-operator, ngrx-store

```
<div class=" d-flex m-0 p-0 mt-2"
[ngClass]="{'justify-content-end': (howMoreSameBook$ | async) < 2,
  'justify-content-between' : (howMoreSameBook$ | async) > 1}">

<p *ngIf="(howMoreSameBook$ | async) > 1" 
class="d-flex align-items-center m-0 p-0" 
[ngStyle]="{'font-weight': 'bold'}">
```

Var howMoreSameBook$ returns number and I want to handles this three conditions.
I got errors `Object is possibly 'null'.ngtsc(2531)`. I know about length method, but in this case i need operations on type: number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `async` pipe is typed that it can also return a `null` value.
That's something that you need to take into account while using it.

For example:

```
(howMoreSameBook$ | async) !== null && (howMoreSameBook$ | async) > 1
```

Or you can workaround this issue with using `!`

```
(howMoreSameBook$ | async)! > 1
```

Comment: Its works :) I don't know char '!' means not less than something so also inculde a null value.